# What does this code mean: `$Odd = ($Odd == "even") ? "odd" : "even";` ?

Tags: php, html, css, string, content-management-system

```
<?php
$Odd = "even";
$query = $MySQLi->query("SELECT id, look, username, motto FROM users WHERE rank =     '7'");
if($query->num_rows > 0):
while($UserRow = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $Odd = ($Odd == "even") ? "odd" : "even";
?>
```

I'm using a CMS for some web. But I don't really understand this code exactly, especially this line:

```
$Odd = ($Odd == "even") ? "odd" : "even";
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Actually for each row it is changing value for `$Odd` with `even` and `odd`.Initially it is `even` . When it comes in loop for first row it becomes `odd` and for second iteration it becomes `even` and so on . This is called conditional operator

Comment: usually when you make tables, you want every two rows to be of a different color, looks better. In this case, that line just toggles between `odd` and `even` over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$Odd = ($Odd == "even") ? "odd" : "even";`

means

```
if($Odd == "even") {
    $Odd = "odd";
}
else {
    $Odd = "even";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It switches between even and odd, each time it is executed. A very $Odd way of putting it :)

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
$Odd = ($Odd == "even") ? "odd" : "even";
```

simply toggles the value of what is initially set to the variable $Odd. So if it is 'even' then it will be changed to 'odd', if it is 'odd' it will be changed to even (for each iteration of the loop). Please be aware that you are also missing a closing curly bracket on the while statement. This is also a rather expensive and lengthy way of doing it though.

Comment: Rather than missing a curly bracket, I'm pretty sure he just didn't post the whole loop. He must be doing something with the result he's fetching (I would hope).

Comment: I am just trying to understand the codes. The codes are already made and they work perfectly, i'm just trying to understand them:) Thank you for your response *-*